# HoloEverywhere xml parsing error/Application crashing

Tags: android, parsing, android-xml, android-logcat, android-holo-everywhere

For some reason, I'm getting this error when using HoloEverywhere. My application crashes on creation and my xml layouts are not displaying for below 3.0. Here is my xml error.

```
Failed to configure parser for C:\Users\Akhil\HoloEverywhere\hololib\res\color\secondary_text_holo_light.xml
Failed to configure parser for C:\Users\Akhil\HoloEverywhere\hololib\res\drawable\background_cache_hint_selector_holo_light.xml
Failed to configure parser for C:\Users\Akhil\HoloEverywhere\hololib\res\color\primary_text_holo_light.xml
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

And here is my logcat. which references an error on line 57 of my activity's onCreate. Line 57 inflates the xml file. This is only happening with HoloEverywhere. Please Help!

```
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sample/com.example.sample.CourseListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:278)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:263)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:258)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:253)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:242)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.example.sample.CourseListActivity.onCreate(CourseListActivity.java:57)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 11 more
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find class: fragment
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:318)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-09 03:01:20.893: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

error log says

```
Could not find class: fragment
```

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) require API Level 11 or greater :)

If you want to use `Fragments` on API < 11 you need to use [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) package for this.

Comment: I am using it. But now I have to use the fragment class given in holoeverywhere. However, using the fragment layout tag is giving me errors. Does anyone know the correct layout tag?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in HoloEverywhere 1.4.1: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/issues/

Did updating to 1.4.1 fix the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your fragment programmatically.
That is, your xml should have only the layout 'content' and, onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
         add(R.id.content, myFragment).commit();
}
```